# More than one version of the flow in the Cordapp

Tags: corda

I would like to have more than one version of certain flow pairs (both the `InitiatingFlow` and `InitiatedBy`) in a node's `cordapps` directory.

The reason for maintaining several copies of certain flow pairs is that some of the nodes may be using a previous version of the flow because they have yet to migrate the version of the flow.

As the flow's version is only in the annotation, I suspect there would be more than one class with the same fully-qualified name. This would result in a runtime error.

Can you provide an example of flow pairs with different versions that can remain in the same `cordapps` folder?

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach here is not to define several flows pairs, but to use the flow version number in the `InitiatingFlow` to control how the corresponding `InitiatedBy` flow behaves.

For example, suppose we have an `InitiatingFlow` that:

- Sends an `Int` in version `1`
- Sends a `String` in subsequent versions

The corresponding `InitiatedBy` flow may look like this:

```
@Suspendable
override fun call() {
    val otherFlowVersion = otherSession.getCounterpartyFlowInfo().flowVersion
    val receivedString = if (otherFlowVersion == 1) {
        otherSession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it.toString() }
    } else {
        otherSession.receive<String>().unwrap { it }
    }
}
```

By using the `InitiatingFlow`'s version number, the `InitiatedBy` flow is able to communicate with parties running any version of the `InitiatingFlow`.

Note that there is no equivalent version number for the `InitiatedBy` flow, which means that the `InitiatingFlow` cannot condition its behaviour on the version of the `InitiatedBy` flow. The `InitiatedBy` flow is the side that must adapt to handle changes in the `InitiatingFlow`, and not vice-versa.

Additional information on flow versioning can be found [here](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-versioning).

Answer (score 0):

Corda has fairly limited versioning model for flows. For example, there is no way for the initiating flow to adapt its behaviour to work with an older version of the responding flow.

The way this could be worked around is through Protocol Handshake pattern. It works like the following. Implement a pair of subflows, say, `InitiatorProtocolHandshakeFlow` and `RespondToProtocolHandshakeFlow`. Make every initiating flow in the CorDapp that establishes a new flow session with another note to invoke `InitiatorProtocolHandshakeFlow` with the counterparty session, and make every responding flow to invoke `RespondToProtocolHandshakeFlow` with the counterparty session before sending or receiving anything else. Make the flows to negotiate relevant 'protocol features'. This could be implemented in a number of way, of which the simplest one to make the responder to send (and initiator to receive) a simple version number. Unlike flow version number in the annotation, the initiating flow can actually alter its behaviour based on the number provided by the responding flow.